# command line switch for sub-directories (dos vs bash) and wildcards

Tags: command-line

Ouch!   Blowing away system clutter from a windows box and this wildcard looks right but did wrong.  I know I should have checked the command first ( use dir /s)

```
C:\WINDOWS>del /f /s /q e:\inetpub\daf*
Deleted file - e:\inetpub\esvc000004\applications\daffodillamp.jpg
```

Am I missing something here?   If I had used ..*daf* then yes I could understand but \daf* means to me only daf* files and directories of daf* naming.  NOT all directories below inetpub looking for daf*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Del` is for files; `rd` is for directories. Your command looks for all files named `daf*` under `e:\inetpub` and all its subdirectories (`/s`)

After decades using cmd and its forebears, I habitually use a `dir` then up-arrow and edit it to a `del`...

Comment: So whats the difference between del /s  and rm /s ?  So what is the best way to delete a directory tree, its directory and contents safely?

Comment: Oh.  it looks like rm command is what I am after.  One command to remove stuff.  Just like unix.

Comment: `RD` or `RMDIR` (synonymous commands) - has the `/s` switch to mean 'and its subdirectories`. `RM` is not a known command - UNLESS you've installed `CYGWIN` which supplies unix-like commands and syntax - but caution - `cygwin` has commands which clash with `CMD` like `FIND` which performs a string-search, not locate-files. Note also `/s` fow switches and `\` for directory-separators. `-` and `/` *sometimes* work in native `cmd` depending on the utility.